# Is there a way to determine if a parameter in a stored proc has a default value (and thus not required) in code - .Net?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

I am already pulling the parameters from the stored proc sent in like this:

```
 foreach (SqlParameter param in cmd.Parameters)
            {
               if ((param.Direction == ParameterDirection.Input) || (param.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput))
                {
                    jsonReturn += "{\"paramName\":\"" + param.ParameterName + "\", \"paramType\":\"" + param.SqlDbType.ToString() + "\"},";
                }
            }
```

I looked into the SqlParameter object and could not find a way to see if it could tell me whether the Parameter had a default value... (although my debugger is acting weird, so who knows).

What I am doing is building a sort of Stored Proc helper for users..  I currently tell them all the parameters that belong to the Stored Proc they pick.... I WOULD REALLY like to be able to tell whether they are required.

Comment: Please add the `sql-server` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, no there is (probably) no way to determine if a stored procedure parameter possesses a default value 'in code' (i.e. using the `SqlParameter` class).

In SQL Server (at least SQL Server 2005), you can query the system catalog view `sys.parameters` (and join it to the catalog view `sys.procedures`) and evaluate the value of the column `has_default_value`.

Answer (score 5):

Update to Devart's SQL - thank you so much, I needed to find what the default values are, not just if they had one, and your code got me started.

It did have a small bug: if a parameter name contained 'at' (like @d_*at*_e), the remaining parameters were not processed.

Using the variables speeds it up a lot, too.

Returns null if no default, otherwise returns everything between the '=' and the ',' in the declaration.

```
declare @ProcName nvarchar(200) = 'your_stored_proc_name'
declare @objectid int
declare @type nchar(2)
declare @oName nvarchar(100)
declare @sName nvarchar(100)
declare @Definition nvarchar(max)


select  @objectid = o.[object_id], 
        @type = o.type, 
        @oName = o.name, 
        @sName = s.name, 
        @Definition = replace(replace(sm.[definition], char(10),' '), char(13),' ')
                    from sys.sql_modules sm WITH (NOLOCK)
                    JOIN sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) ON sm.[object_id] = o.[object_id] 
                    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
                    WHERE o.[type] IN ('P ', 'FN', 'IF', 'TF')
                        AND s.name + '.' + o.name =  @ProcName 

    SELECT
          data2.[object_name] as StoredProcedure
        , data2.name as ParameterName
        , DefaultValue = 
            CASE WHEN data2.ptoken LIKE '%=%' 
                THEN SUBSTRING(data2.ptoken, CHARINDEX('=', data2.ptoken)+1, CHARINDEX(',',data2.ptoken+',',CHARINDEX('=', data2.ptoken))-CHARINDEX('=', data2.ptoken)-1)
                ELSE null
            END
    FROM (
        SELECT  
              data.name
            , data.[object_name]
            , ptoken = SUBSTRING(
                    data.tokens
                , token_pos + name_length + 1
                , ISNULL(ABS(next_token_pos - token_pos - name_length - 1), LEN(data.tokens))
            )
        FROM (
            SELECT  
                  sm3.tokens
                , sm3.[object_name]
                , p.name
                , name_length = LEN(p.name)
                , token_pos = CHARINDEX(p.name, sm3.tokens)
                , next_token_pos = CHARINDEX(p2.name, sm3.tokens)
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                      sm2.[object_id]
                    , sm2.[type]
                    , sm2.[object_name]
                    , tokens = REVERSE(
                        CASE WHEN sm2.[type] IN ('FN', 'TF', 'IF') 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(sm2.tokens, ISNULL(CHARINDEX(N')', sm2.tokens) + 1, 0), LEN(sm2.tokens)) 
                            ELSE SUBSTRING(sm2.tokens, ISNULL(CHARINDEX(' SA ', sm2.tokens) + 2, 0), LEN(sm2.tokens))  
                        END
                    ) 
                FROM (
                    SELECT 
                          @objectid as [object_id]
                        , @type as [type]
                        , @sName + '.' + @oName as [object_name] 
                        , tokens = REVERSE(CASE WHEN @type IN ('FN', 'TF', 'IF') 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(
                                      @Definition
                                    , CHARINDEX(N'(', @Definition) + 1
                                    , ABS(CHARINDEX(N'RETURNS', @Definition) - CHARINDEX(N'(', @Definition) - 1)
                                    ) 
                            ELSE SUBSTRING(
                                      @Definition
                                    , CHARINDEX(@oName, @Definition) + LEN(@oName) + 1
                                    , ABS(CHARINDEX(N' AS ', @Definition) - (CHARINDEX(@oName, @Definition) + LEN(@oname) + 1))
                                    )  
                            END
                            )
                ) sm2
                WHERE sm2.tokens LIKE '%=%'
            ) sm3
            JOIN sys.parameters p WITH (NOLOCK) ON sm3.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
            OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT p2.name
                FROM sys.parameters p2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
                WHERE p2.is_output = 0
                    AND sm3.[object_id] = p2.[object_id] 
                    AND p.parameter_id + 1 = p2.parameter_id
            ) p2
            WHERE p.is_output = 0
        ) data
    ) data2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query. It returns default values for any stored procedure/function -

```
SELECT
      data2.[object_name]   
    , data2.name
    , has_default_value = 
        CASE WHEN data2.ptoken LIKE '%=%' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
FROM (
    SELECT  
          data.name
        , data.[object_name]
        , ptoken = SUBSTRING(
                data.tokens
            , token_pos + name_length + 1
            , ISNULL(ABS(next_token_pos - token_pos - name_length - 1), LEN(data.tokens))
        )
    FROM (
        SELECT  
              sm3.tokens
            , sm3.[object_name]
            , p.name
            , name_length = LEN(p.name)
            , token_pos = CHARINDEX(p.name, sm3.tokens)
            , next_token_pos = CHARINDEX(p2.name, sm3.tokens)
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                  sm2.[object_id]
                , sm2.[type]
                , sm2.[object_name]
                , tokens = REVERSE(
                    CASE WHEN sm2.[type] IN ('FN', 'TF', 'IF') 
                        THEN SUBSTRING(sm2.tokens, ISNULL(CHARINDEX(N')', sm2.tokens) + 1, 0), LEN(sm2.tokens)) 
                        ELSE SUBSTRING(sm2.tokens, ISNULL(CHARINDEX('SA', sm2.tokens) + 2, 0), LEN(sm2.tokens))  
                    END
                ) 
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                      sm.[object_id]
                    , o.[type]
                    , [object_name] = s.name + '.' + o.name
                    , tokens = REVERSE(CASE WHEN o.[type] IN ('FN', 'TF', 'IF') 
                        THEN SUBSTRING(
                                  sm.[definition]
                                , CHARINDEX(N'(', sm.[definition]) + 1
                                , ABS(CHARINDEX(N'RETURNS', sm.[definition]) - CHARINDEX(N'(', sm.[definition]) - 1)
                                ) 
                        ELSE SUBSTRING(
                                  sm.[definition]
                                , CHARINDEX(o.name, sm.[definition]) + LEN(o.name) + 1
                                , ABS(CHARINDEX(N'AS', sm.[definition]))
                                )  
                        END
                    ) 
                FROM sys.sql_modules sm WITH (NOLOCK)
                JOIN sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) ON sm.[object_id] = o.[object_id] 
                JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
                WHERE o.[type] IN ('P ', 'FN', 'IF', 'TF')
                    AND s.name + '.' + o.name = 'dbo.usp_test1'
            ) sm2
            WHERE sm2.tokens LIKE '%=%'
        ) sm3
        JOIN sys.parameters p WITH (NOLOCK) ON sm3.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT p2.name
            FROM sys.parameters p2 WITH (NOLOCK) 
            WHERE p2.is_output = 0
                AND sm3.[object_id] = p2.[object_id] 
                AND p.parameter_id + 1 = p2.parameter_id
        ) p2
        WHERE p.is_output = 0
    ) data
) data2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at developing tools for management of SQL Server objects then a better option may be [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx). It looks like you can get to the default value of a stored procedure parameter using the [StoredProcedureParameter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220419%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.parameter.defaultvalue(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: Here's an example of code using this approach. I've verified that it does in fact get the default values for regular old non-CLR stored procs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676272