# How to get required parameters from a stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When we try to execute a stored procedure without sending values to it's required parameter , it gives an error like below.

[image]

**I wanna know, is there any way to problematically capture the all parameters for a given stored procedure ?**

**Eg: Parr[] string =  GetSpParameters("StoredProcedureName);**
//I need to develop the "GetSpParameters" function.

Thanks.

Comment: I wanna get a list of parameters from a given sp in C#, not in SQL server.

Comment: The "duplicate" question covers how to get a list of parameters for a proc, but it doesn't cover the real need of this question, which was how to get a list of _**required**_ parameters (i.e., parameters without a default value) for a proc.  For that, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676272

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx) method to populate the Parameters collection of the specified SqlCommand object.

Comment: Thank you. it works. here is my code.
----------------------
                SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(SqlCmd);
   
                foreach (SqlParameter parameter in SqlCmd.Parameters)
                {
                    
                }
----------------------
thanks.

Comment: note that this doesn't actually tell you if the parameters are required or optional; that information is significantly harder to get. I'll have an answer forthcoming on that.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server terms, a required parameter is any parameter that does not have a default value, e.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo
(
  @Required INT,
  @NotRequired INT = NULL
)
```

In this case, you *can* call the procedure without the `@NotRequired` parameter, but you *can't* call the procedure without the `@Required` one -- you'll get the error in your question.

You can use `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` on a `SqlCommand` object you've set up to populate the `Parameters` collection, but that will not tell you the difference between optional and required parameters. You could to just assume that all stored procedure parameters are required, but that's a terrible idea. Stored procedures very often allow you to pass various combinations of parameters, and behave appropriately. For example, a "search" stored procedure may take a big list of parameters but only require you to specify the ones you really want to search for; or a stored procedure may have default values for certain parameter and only expect you to specify explicit values if you want to change the behavior.

To actually tell the difference, you need to use the SQL Server SMO API. This should be installed as part of the SQL Server client tools setup, you'll need to add a reference to several assemblies: `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk`, and `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo`.

From there, the basic idea is:

```
var server = new Server("instancename");
server.ConnectionContext.DatabaseName = "DatabaseName";
server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
server.ConnectionContext.Connect();

var db = server.Databases["databasename"];
var proc = new StoredProcedure(db, "storedprocedurename");

foreach (StoredProcedureParameter parameter in sp.Parameters)
{
    if (parameter.DefaultValue != null)
    {
      // param is required.
    }
}
```

You can see more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038364/get-stored-procedure-parameters-by-either-c-sharp-or-sql) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528472/how-can-i-retrieve-sql-stored-procedure-parameters-with-smo-more-efficently) and [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162190.aspx). In particular, that second question talks about ways to speed up this process by telling SMO not to load some information you won't care about.

Comment: Michael, I am getting an error 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Server' does not contain a definition for 'Connect', I also checked the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.aspx) page for the 'Server' class, it does not have a method with that name, please explain.

Comment: yes, sorry, it was a transcription error. it's `ConnectionContext.Connect()`.